# Using a 2D array global variable in C when I only know one dimension at compile-time

Tags: c, arrays, variables, 2d, global

My situation is odd. I have a global 2D array of chars (meant to represent an array of strings). These strings will have a length no greater than 28, including the terminating character, so I just want to use a 2D array with one dimension set to 28. The other dimension is determined at compile-time, but my program counts how many slots it will need before it allocates the array.

I'm trying to declare the array like this (global):

```
char** dictionary;
```

Then in one of my functions, I need to allocate it. These two give me bad access errors once I try to access them with dictionary[0][0] or something:

```
dictionary = malloc(sizeof(char)*(28)*numberWords); //numberWords ends up being around 60000
//separately:
char newDict[numberWords][28];
dictionary = newDict;
```

Yes, I'm kinda new to C. Wish my school taught me it instead of Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char newDict[numberWords][28];
dictionary = newDict;
```

first off this part is wrong, newDict is an array, its allocated in one segment of memory, whereas dictionary is a pointer to pointer its scatterd in different parts of the Heap, you get bad access because dictionary is looking for a pointer to a pointer, and newdict does not contain pointers, read up on Arrays and pointers, they are different although they seem to work in similar ways

I see that you want to use array notation hence you assign dictionaty = newdict(this is wrong)

easiset way to do this is

```
char ** dictionary;
 dictionary = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*NUMBER_OF_WORDS)

 for(int i =0;i<NUM_WORDS,i++)
 {
 dictionary[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*28);
 }

 now you can access each word like this 
 dictionary[word_number][the letter]; 

 //so in your code you said char ** dictionaty, lets go through this, dictionary is a 
   pointer to another pointer that points to a char. look at my code, dictionary is a 
   pointer, that points to another pointer that eventuall points to a char.
```

why does this work?

array notation works like this a[x] = *(a+x) , in other words go to the array a, add x and take the number in that memory location the square brackets is called syntactic sugar, just to make our life easier, what really happens is *(a+x).

for a 2d array a[x][y] =  * ( *(a+x) + y) this is saying go to the pointer a, add x to the pointer take what ever is in that memory *(a+x) and then add y to that memory and take whatever that points to * (* (a+x) + y)

please note when i say add x to the pointer, it depends on what the array hold, say if you have an array of  ints, since an int is 4 bytes, and lets say x is 1,

```
int a[10]
a[1] = *(a+1) (the compiler actually adds 4 bytes to the address although we 
said 1  obviously since an int is 4 bytes, this 
is pointer arithmetic you should read up on it. this makes things much easier.
```

what really happens in memory is that 4 bytes are added to go to the address of a+1, the compiler takes care of this for us, so this makes things much easier, in you case its a char, so say a[1] = *(a+1),

back to your question.

dictionary[0][0] will give you the first letter in your 1st word, to get the entire string you   something like printf with a %s since your strings are null terminated.

Comment: Thanks. All of these answers are possible solutions, but this is more what I was asking for. But maybe I should do it a different way for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a global access to the strings and you know the largest length of the string but you don't know how many strings you want to have until program execution, then you could declare a global pointer to an char array[28]. Also the benefit here is that memory is contiguous.

```
#define MAX 28

char ( *p_array)[MAX] ;

void func( int size )
{
    p_array = malloc( sizeof( *p_array ) * size ) ;

    for( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
        snprintf( p_array[i] , sizeof( *p_array ) , "test string no.: %d" , i ) ;

    for( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
        printf("%s\n" , p_array[i] ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare

```
char newDict[numberWords][28];
```

then newDict is *not* a `char **`, but an actual two-dimensional array of characters, so the assignment won't work.  On the other hand, I think that `newDict` declaration is the right way to go.  If you really want this global pointer thing, then perhaps something like

```
typedef char String[28]; //a String is a single array of 28 chars
String* dictionary;
```

would be compatible with your declaration of `newDict` (since array-to-pointer decay only works on the "outer" level, not recursively to all levels).